# Define a Style for a Button when Hover in a universal App

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have tried to define this style when I hover on each button in the designer,like this:

[image]

but I get this result when I hover on each Button with my code:
[image]
[image]

this is my code,I have defined a style for the Button:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtontopStyle1" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#e6e6e6"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#e6e6e6" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Button1" />
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#393185" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Button11" />
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#393185" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Content11" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#e6e6e6" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Button1" />
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#393185" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Content11" />

                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content11" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="Button1" Stroke="Transparent" Fill="Transparent" Margin="0"  Width="auto"/>
                        </Grid>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="Button11" Stroke="Transparent" Fill="Transparent" Margin="0" Grid.Column="1" Width="5"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

then I have apply it in my button like that:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0" >
    <Button  Background="Transparent" Content="Resultats" FontSize="18" Foreground="#727271"  x:Name="res" Style="{Binding Source={StaticResource ButtontopStyle1}}" />
    <StackPanel x:Name="stackVisible" Orientation="Vertical" >
        <Button  Background="Transparent" Content="Tous les résultats" FontSize="16"  Foreground="#727271"   x:Name="ttres" Style="{Binding Source={StaticResource ButtontopStyle1}}"
        <Button Background="Transparent" Content="Recherches Avancées" FontSize="16"  Foreground="#727271"  x:Name="rechavan"  Style="{Binding Source={StaticResource ButtontopStyle1}}" />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

as you can see,when I hover,I have a rectangle that hides the text of the Button

How can I modify my code to be like the result that I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do something like this :

```
<Style  x:Key="ButtontopStyle1"
        TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Foreground"
            Value="#e6e6e6" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0"
                                                    To="#e6e6e6"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="Button1" />
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0"
                                                    To="#393185"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="Button11" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0"
                                                    To="#e6e6e6"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="Button1" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                            <Rectangle x:Name="Button1"
                                       Stroke="Transparent"
                                       Fill="Transparent"
                                       Margin="0"
                                       Width="auto" />
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content11"
                                              Background="Transparent"
                                              Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                        </Grid>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="Button11"
                                   Stroke="Transparent"
                                   Fill="Transparent"
                                   Margin="0"
                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                   Width="5" />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: I have a question Sir why did you use this line?

Comment: <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content11"   Background="Transparent"   Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />

Comment: because I suppose you don't want modify the Foreground property directly in the Template. So {TemplateBinding Foreground} means the Foreground value declared at the Button level (<Button Foreground="Red" />). If you force the Foreground value in the Template, you can't override them at the Button declaration level. In your sample, I propose to set the Brackground property to Transparent in order to not interfere with the color of Button1 and Button11 (maybe they are important for you?), but you can remove Button1 and Button11 and just set the property of the ContentPresenter in your Storyboard